# Why my program skips a for cicle? C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, valgrind

im trying to code a function that splits a string onto multiple ones, i know I have alot of allocated space not freed, I'm just testing this bit but valgrind displays me

```
 Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==25613==    at 0x4C2DB3C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)  
==25613==    by 0x40090C: split (strutil.c:32)  
==25613==    by 0x400A00: main (strutil.c:45)  
==25613==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation  
==25613==    at 0x400720: split (strutil.c:9)
```

a few similar errors and then sigsem and closes. my concern is that when i run it with gdb in that for circle thats supposed to count the ',' it circles as expected until it reaches the value ',' then skips entire cicle but the i++ and keeps going. Why does it do that? I watched over gdb and all the parameters (str[i] , sep) have the correct values inside at the moment before the conditional.

```
#include "strutil.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(const char* str, char sep){
size_t cant = 2;
size_t i;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){//this is line 9
    if(str[i] == sep)
        cant ++;
    i++;
}
size_t corte[cant];
i = 0;
corte[0] = 0;
size_t j = 1;
size_t cant_corte[cant];
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){
    if(str[i] == sep){
        corte[j] = i + 1;
        cant_corte[j - 1] = corte[j] - corte[j - 1];
        //printf("pasa\n"); 
        j++;
    }
    printf("pasa\n"); 
    i++;
}
char** strv = malloc(sizeof(char*) * cant);
    if (strv == NULL)return NULL;
for(i=0; i < cant; i++){
    strv[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * cant_corte[i]);
    if (strv[i] == NULL)return NULL;
    strncpy(strv[i], str + corte[i], cant_corte[i-1]);
    strcat(strv[i], "\0");
}
strv[cant + 2] = NULL;
return strv;
}

int main(){
char* eje = "abc,defg";
printf("%s\n", eje);
char r = ',';
char** prueba = split(eje, r);
printf("%s\n", prueba[0]);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'cant_corte[i-1]' - UB for i=0

Comment: `strv[cant + 2] = NULL;` : this occurs out-of-bounds.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What? `strv` is a return value of `malloc`, which certainly is testable. `if (*strv == NULL)` would be something different, and valgrind would be totally correct to complain about that.

Comment: Your first two `for` loops are only using even indices `i`. Was that intentional?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm fairly familiar with valgrind, have never seen this malloc-in-valgrind bug you're talking about, and can't reproduce it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156398/discussion-between-aschepler-and-david-c-rankin).

Comment: @aschepler - I have been working on a test case, and I have hit this at least 100 times, but I cannot reproduce it on `valgrind-3.11.0` as I thought I could, it must have been on an earlier version. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want your `i` variable to continue to increment, then make sure in your for loop you do not increment `i`, and instead depend on the for loop to do its' job. ( increment i every time the condition is true ).

Comment: I've gone crazy and the thing is that i was using a while before the forloop, and didnt chage the i++ really sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Not a waste of my time, simple mistakes are the hard ones sometimes.